# Let f be a continuous 1-1 function which is it's own inverse - prove that $f$ is monotonic decreasing.

Tags: real-analysis

on $I=[a,b]$ $f=f^{-1}$ Now, it's also given that $f$ is continuous and 1-to-1.

$$f(f(x))=x$$ Taking derivatives, by the chain rule : $$f'(f(x))f'(x)=1$$

Now from here SOMEHOW we concluded that $f'(x)<0$ I couldn't get how. Can anybody explain?

Also, Let's use the graph approach. let $G$ be the graph of $f$. Take two points $p_1=(x,f(x)) $ and $p_2=(y,f(y))$ in $G$ where $y>x$ Taking the reflection of $G$ we end up with

$p_1'=(f(x),x)=(x,f(x))$ and $p_2'=(f(y),y)=(y,f(y))$ if $f$ was an increasing function then $f(y)>f(x)$ So but this would imply that $$y=f(y)>x=f(x)$$

This approach didn't seem to work as well. Couldn't find a contradiction. Any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: You can't use differentiation since you only know that $f$ is continuous. You don't know if it's differentiable.

Comment: No I can $f$ is continuous on a compact interval and $1-1$ then $f$ is a strictly monotonic function.

Comment: Are you sure that you've stated the problem correctly? Consider $f(x)=x$ which clearly satisfies the hypotheses, but not the conclusion.

Comment: This works except for the function $y=x$,

Answer (score 1):

Counter-example to what you want to prove.

Let $f(x)=x$, it is continuous and it is its own inverse, but it is not monotonically decreasing.

Comment: Yep, this is the only counter example. This implies to all other functions except $f(x)=x$

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is bijective, $f$ is strictly monotone.

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Injection_of_Interval_is_Strictly_Monotone

Suppose that $f$ is not the identity and is increasing. There exists $x\in [a,b]$ with $f(x)\neq x$. Suppose that $f(x)>x$, since $f$ is increasing, $f(f(x))=x\geq f(x)>x$ contradiction.

Suppose that $x<f(x)$, we have $f(x)\leq f(f(x))=x$ contradiction.

Example: $f:[-1,1]\rightarrow [-1,1]$ defined by $f(x)=-x$.